# Same code, same input but different output in Appwrite function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, appwrite

I have been on this issue for a while now, and still cannot find a solution.

I'm currently working on a JS/TS Vue App (using the project scaffolding by Quasar framework).
We have an on premise Appwrite server with cloud functions enabled.

I'm trying to port some of the code to a single Appwrite function.
The function listens for POST requests with a JSON object as the body and returns the result as a JSON object.

**Appwrite server version : 1.4.4 (I'm not the admin)**

**Local node version 20 or 21**

**Appwrite Node version 18.0**

## The problem

The issue is : The code in the function doesn't give me the same output as when the code is tested locally.

## Context

Basically, I have a 3 Typescript files containing classes A, B and C that import different things from eachother, that's why I include them all for the function. Class A has a method `processJson(json): json` that is the one I'm trying to turn into a single Appwrite function.

Since Appwrite functions have a Node 18.0 runtime, I first need to transpile the files to Javascript.
As I don't have a lot of experience with that, I use the [`tsup`](https://github.com/egoist/tsup) package to build the files like so :

1. Create an empty dir somewhere
2. Copy file A.ts, B.ts and C.ts to this dir
3. CD to the dir
4. Run `npx tsup --format esm A.ts B.ts C.ts` which outputs to `./dist/A.mjs` `./dist/B.mjs` `./dist/C.mjs`
5. Move the `dist` dir inside the dir of the Appwrite function, so I end up with something like this : `somepath/appwrite/functions/myfunction/dist/...` and `somepath/appwrite/functions/myfunction/main.js` (the Appwrite function). Inside `main.js` I then import the compiled depedency like `import { MyClass } from './dist/A.mjs'`
6. Finally, I deploy the function to Appwrite using the [CLI](https://appwrite.io/docs/tooling/command-line/deployment#deploying-function). So `npx appwrite deploy function`, select my function and deploy it.

The function deploys successfully (no build or deploy error) and I'm able to query it through Postman, Python and Appwrite's UI by sending a POST request with the (non stringified) JSON test object that I have. The function does return wihtout crashing, but the result is not the one I expect.

When testing the code locally (with the Quasar app in dev mode), with the same JSON as input I get output A, when testing that same JSON with the function, I get output B.

So far I tried :

- Deploying the same code on a different function: same issue
- Using NVM to test locally with the same Node version as Appwrite (Node 18.0) : local test works, same issue for the function. I was thinking maybe some syntax I used was too recent for version 18.0...
- Make small tweaks to the functions `main.js` file and redeploy to see if changes were actually pushed : changes are pushed

I don't really know what to do next, as I said, I'm not familiar with Typescript building, and I used the flag --format esm with `tsup` as I was getting import errors otherwise (CommonJS, etc).

I just have a feeling that the problem has to be related to this somehow, as I feel I've tried everything else so maybe there's something obvious that I'm missing...